# converting into a type-erased tuple

Tags: c++, c++14, signals-slots

While writing a signal/slot system I instantiate a template function `invoker`:

```
template <typename F, typename ...A, ::std::size_t ...I>
inline void do_invoke(F const& f, ::std::tuple<A...> const& t,
  ::std::index_sequence<I...> const)
{
  f(::std::get<I>(t)...);
}

template <typename F, typename ...A>
inline void invoker(variant_type const& v, void const* const v)
{
  do_invoke<F, A...>(get<F>(v),
    *static_cast<::std::tuple<A...> const*>(v),
    ::std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(A)>());
}
```

Here `variant_type` is any container of type-erased objects (like `::boost::any`, for example, but could be anything). The problem is the assumption that `v` points to `::std::tuple<A...>`, which may not be true, but the tuple `v` points to might still be convertible into `::std::tuple<A...>`. I don't know what `A...` was anymore, when I make a call to `invoker()` as this information has been erased. Hence, I cannot do:

```
template <typename ...A, typename ...B, ::std::size_t ...I>
::std::tuple<A...> convert(::std::tuple<B...> const& t,
::std::index_sequence<I...> const)
{
  return ::std::tuple<A...>{::std::get<I>(t)...};
}
```

before calling. If the tuple types don't match exactly, I have UB. Is there a way out of this situation?

Comment: Why don't you erase args in an object which know the `variant_type` (and so do the conversion a place where all type are known) ?

Comment: The full code is here: https://github.com/janezz55/crl/blob/master/object.hpp I suppose that, yes, I shoud type erase the arguments also and convert, void* is dangerous.

Comment: `std::unordered_map<char const*, ::std::vector<slot_info>`... using those **pointer** as key seems dangerous, you probably want `std::string` instead (to use content string instead of comparing only pointer).

Comment: Yes, but I didn't ask about that :) The assumption is we use literals as keys.

Comment: In addition, to forward argument to several functions is suspicious too, (as if first function take ownership of the resource, next functions got *nullified* resource (in best case)).

Comment: An other question is how to handle mismatch type in your design...

Comment: Even with literals, `"foo" == "foo"` is not guarantied.

Comment: I know, but it's nowadays almost always so.

Answer (score 1):

I see the following options:

1. Delay moving the data into the type erased structure.
2. Move the call to invoker into the type erased structure, e.g. by passing the invoker instance as an argument (of course, this only works if there is just one (or at least very few well known instances of) invoker.
3. If the number of types `A` is small enough and known at the time you construct the type erased structure, you might could implement some cast to `A` that throws if it does not match. Not nice, but also not undefined behavior.
4. Instead of type-erasing the tuple, type-erase the individual tuple elements, store them in a vector and call f on them. Of course that means you have to be able to call f on your erased type but if the number of different f is small, this might be much easier to accomplish.

Comment: How to delay moving the data? You mean some kind of data marshalling?

Comment: I meant the steps from wherever you create the original tuple to storing it in the type_erased structure. Currently you have create < store < invoke. Try to delay storing to get create < invoke < store. Easy for me to say, I know.

Comment: You mean invoke would pull in arguments from somewhere. I don't really know how to implement that. Expand your answer perhaps with examples, please?

Comment: No, I meant that you are calling `Object::do_connect` with template arguments which make assumptions about the types of the type-erased data that's stored. Maybe you could instead make `Object` a template and store the non-type-erased data instead. And then maybe type-erase the `Object` instances when you store those somewhere.